# XQuery update for document with versions

Tags: database, version, xquery, xquery-sql

I am trying to update value of some property in xDB using XQuery, here is my transaction:

```
let $source := doc('/historicalresource')/HistoricalResourceData[id/@UUID = '0361513e-30fa-45e4-a73a-d05870b8a284']

let $res := $source/ResourceProperty[@PropertyName="cpu|limit"]/@PropertyValue

let $change := '21572'

return replace value of node $res with $change
```

After running this query I receive such error:

> com.xhive.error.XhiveException: VERSION_ACCESS_DENIED: This document
>   is versioned and can only be changed through a versioning operation

Indeed in my case `historicalresource` is a folder which may contain more than one document and all they have a version, like: v1.1 ,v1.2, etc..

How can I update the value of last version using xquery? 
How should I modify my query to be able to update desired value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found the answer to my question, therefore adding it here:

There is no way to update xDB file using xQuery as it is version based system and xQuery cannot create a new version, but it could be done manually or automatically by some coding language (for example: java):

1. Manually - by editing existing version in xDB, in that case a new version will be automatically created after saving any change to existing version of the file.
2. Automatically - by checking out the file, making the change and submitting the change as a new version.

Answer (score 0):

For versioned documents (on which `XhiveLibraryChildIf.makeVersionable()` was called), this is indeed the case: you have to check out the document first, then run the update query on the checked out copy, and finally check the new version in. For non-versioned documents, however, you can apply the update query directly.